# I want to store the text the user types into this text box into a variable ..how? I am using pyqt5

Tags: python, variables, pyqt5, textbox

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QButtonGroup, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QWidget, QSizeGrip, QLabel, QFormLayout, QScrollArea, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
import sys

class main_window(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__ (self):
    super(main_window, self).__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("Polynomial Equation Solver")
    self.setFixedSize(957, 681)
    self.setStyleSheet("background-image : url(Background1.jpg)")

    degree_textbox = QTextEdit(self)
    degree_textbox.setGeometry(460, 25, 200, 40)
    degree_textbox.setStyleSheet("background-image : url(Text boxes background.jpg)")
```

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window=main_window()
window.show()

app.exec_()

Comment: You don't need to "store" anything, you can access it with [`toPlainText()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText), as long as you keep a reference to the widget: change any reference of `degree_textbox` to `self.degree_textbox` and then use `self.degree_textbox.toPlainText()` from the instance or `window.degree_textbox.toPlainText()` from elsewhere. I also suggest you to do more studying on what classes and instances are, what's the purpose of `self` in python, and also take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and how to [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).